# how to hide a column in SELECT

Tags: sql, pgadmin

I have to get a column that a select to be hidden. More specificaly s.spelersnr but I can't figure out how.

I tried the select a column to be used in my ORDER BY but I don't want to let it show in the result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT naam,voorletters, TO_CHAR(geb_datum,'dd-mm-yyyy') AS 
geboortedatum, b.spelersnr
FROM spelers s LEFT OUTER JOIN boetes b
 ON (s.spelersnr = b.spelersnr)
WHERE b.bedrag<75 OR b.bedrag IS null
ORDER BY b.spelersnr
```

I should get a result without the colum b.spelersnr.
But I do get that one how do I hide it?

Comment: You can do `ORDER BY b.spelersnr` without selecting the column `b.spelersnr`

Comment: When SELECT DISTINCT only selected items may be specified in the ORDER BY. Makes perfect sense! Consider (c1, c2) values (1,1), (2,2), (3,1), now do `select distinct c2`, of course you can't order by c1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT naam, voorletters, TO_CHAR(geb_datum,'dd-mm-yyyy') AS  geboortedatum
FROM spelers s LEFT JOIN
     boetes b
     ON s.spelersnr = b.spelersnr
WHERE b.bedrag < 75 OR b.bedrag IS null
GROUP BY naam, voorletters, geboortedatum, b.spelersnr
ORDER BY b.spelersnr;
```

I cannot fathom why you would want to do this -- generating duplicate results, when the column causing the duplication is hidden.

I am guessing that you don't want this logic, but instead:

```
FROM spelers s LEFT JOIN
     boetes b
     ON s.spelersnr = b.spelersnr AND b.bedrag < 75
```

This returns all rows from `spelers` with matching values from `boetes` where `b.bedrag < 75`.